# Integration, show that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x)}{ (1+i\cdot x)^k} dx\ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f(t)$ be real analytic, symmetric, positive, and bounded. Is it true that
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x)}{ (1+i\cdot x)^k} dx\ge 0
\end{align}
for any $k\ge 2$.

Comment: Have you check the case when $f(x)=1$?

Comment: @JackyChong yes, it's always equal to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. By the residue theorem
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)^2}{(1+ix)^5}\,dx = -\frac{\pi}{3e^2} < 0$$
and in general there is no reason for expecting that the positivity of an even analytic function over the real line implies something about the sign of a residue at $x=i$.

Comment: What would be an example of a function with complex answer?

Comment: @Boby: I am modifying my answer. We have $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{(\sin(x)-\cos(x))^2}{(1+ix)^5}\,dx = \frac{2\pi i}{3e^2},$$ but here $(\sin(x)-\cos(x))^2$ is not an even function. So, fixing the previous answer: parity ensures that the integral is real, but positivity does not ensure that the integral is positive.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x)=x^2/(1+x^2)$ which is definitely symmetric, positive and bounded. Let $k=2$ then we see that 
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{x^2}{(1+ix)^2(1+x^2)}\ dx=& \int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{(1-ix)^2x^2}{(1+x^2)^3}\ dx\\
=&\ \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{(1-x^2- 2ix)x^2}{(1+x^2)^3}\ dx \\
=&\ \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{ (1-x^2)x^2}{(1+x^2)^3}\ dx=-\frac{\pi}{4} <0.
\end{align}

Comment: I don't think. $f(x)$ you have is analytic it only converse for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Taylor expand about another point.

Comment: Remember $z^2/(1+z^2)$ is analytic everywhere expect $z=\pm i$.